# SHOW TABLES statement with multiple LIKE values

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES like 'cms';
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_tianyan (cms) |
+-------------------------+
| cms                     |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Result

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES like 'cms' or like 'role';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual...
```

How can I filter by multiple conditions ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to use the `WHERE` clause. As shown in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html), you can only have a single pattern if you use `"SHOW TABLES LIKE ..."`, but you can use an expression in the WHERE clause if you use `"SHOW TABLES WHERE ..."`. Since you want an expression, you need to use the `WHERE` clause.

```
SHOW TABLES
FROM `<yourdbname>`
WHERE 
    `Tables_in_<yourdbname>` LIKE '%cms%'
    OR `Tables_in_<yourdbname>` LIKE '%role%';
```

Comment: You need to define the db name in the `FROM` clause - this query will return tables from any database served by the MySQL instance.

Answer (score 17):

You can just use a normal SQL `WHERE` statement to do it.

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_tianyan LIKE '%cms%'
```

Comment: I want to filter by `like 'cms' or like 'role'`, and it seems `WHERE Tables_in_tianyan` is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 7):

```
show tables from mydb 
where 
  Tables_in_mydb like '%statistics%' 
  or Tables_in_mydb like '%device%';
```

Answer (score 3):

You take table list using the below code

```
select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

this will help

```
SELECT 
TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME
 LIKE 'cms%';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_<yourdbname> REGEXP '^(regex-pattern1|regex-pattern2|...)$';
```