# MySql show tables query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the tables names in my database using this query

```
show tables LIKE 'table1%'
```

it's working fine but at the same table I have a version of the table with some columns empty called 'table1_blank'. When I use the above statement I get every table starting with table1 including the "blank", how do I exclude 'table1_blank' from the selection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multiple like clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5609620/724591) using the where condition for `SHOW TABLES`:

```
SHOW TABLES 
FROM `dbname` 
WHERE `Tables_In_dbname` LIKE 'table1%' 
  AND `Tables_In_dbname` NOT LIKE 'table1\_%';
```

Comment: Thanks. It still returned table1 and table1_blank but I used it with Junsu Heo's other way of selecting tables using information_schema and it worked.

Comment: Hmm, I would have had to seen the query that was ran. I created two tables called table1 and table1_blank to test it.

Answer (score 0):

'_' has special meaning. 'any one character', so you need to change like this..

**EDITED**

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your database name'
   AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'table1%'
   AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'table1\_%';
```

Comment: show tables LIKE 'table1\_%'  this is giving me table1_blank only.

Comment: @crimson oops. I misunderstood you question.