# Table '...' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

i know my question is duplicate,but my scenario is different just hear me out

i am using a table of a plugin named **gravity forms** in wordpress for some custom manipulation of data now i am being returned an error!

```
Table 'printam1_i322754_wp1.wp_rj_lead_detail' doesn't exist
```

now i did some research. In the sql section of my database what i did is i ran some code to check whether my table exists or not the table i am trying to access is **wp_rj_lead_detail** 
now when i run a query in sql mode inside phpmyadmin

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wp_rj_lead_detail'
```

0 rows are returned but my table actually exist i can see it and when i run the same query  with some other table name like
`SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wp_links'` it returns a row which means table exist! i was thinking all the time about the issue being on development side whereas the issue was on database side. can anyone guide me what is the issue? i also downloaded the whole db and its size is whooping 98M! is it normal? because the site has only one proper quotation page else the website is pretty much empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the previous post:
[SHOW TABLES statement with multiple LIKE values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609620/show-tables-statement-with-multiple-like-values)

You are missing a few key points.  The biggest one at a quick glance was the missing wildcards '%wp_rj_lead_detail%'.

```
    SHOW TABLES
    FROM `<yourdbname>`
    WHERE 
         `Tables_in_<yourdbname>` LIKE '%cms%';
```

While the multiple like values does not apply, the logic does.

Comment: sorry for the late reply! this was not actually the solution,but i found the solution through your answer keep up the good work Jay!