# Show table with multiple conditions in Databricks

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, databricks, aws-databricks

I want to find tables in my databricks database that meet more than one condition. Mysql allows 'where' clauses to include multiple conditions like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609620/show-tables-statement-with-multiple-like-values) explains.

To use multiple conditions in databricks, I can use the following syntax, but this is an or clause:

```
show tables from {database} like "*2008*|*animal*"
```

I want to find all tables that have** both 2008 and animal** in the name. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a spark dataframe, then select from it. Here I converted the DF to a temp view and then wrote plain SQL against the view.

```
Cmd-1: 
%python

df = spark.sql("show tables in {}".format("your_db_name"))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_tempview")
```

--

```
Cmd-2: 
%sql

select *
from df_tempview
where tableName like ('%2008%') and tableName like ('%animal%')
```